# When is it preferable to pass variables to methods vs. read attributes in python

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

When working within a class, I often chain calculations together, passing results from one method to another.

I have used two ways of doing this: Option 1, store the variables as attributes, then read those attributes in the next method; or Option 2, explicitly return and pass variables between methods.

**Option 1, storing results as attributes**

```
class MyClass:
    def method1(self):
        ... code that generates result1 and result2 ...
        self.result1 = result1
        self.result2 = result2
    def method2(self):
        ... code that generates result3 using result1 and result2 ...
        self.result3 = result3
```

**Option 2, returning and explicitly passing in variables**

```
class MyClass:
    def method1(self):
        ... code that generates result1 and result2 ...
        return result1, result2
    def method2(self, result1, result2):
        ... code that generates result3 using result1 and result2 ...
        return result3
```

Option 1 has the problem where it's unclear 'method2' requires 'result1' and 'result2'. If we forget that we need to run 'method1', we could get confusing errors.

Option 2 solves this, as we clearly need 'result1' and 'result2' for 'method2'. However it feels a little messy, especially if the method requires a large number of inputs. It also feels like it defeats the point of having access to the all attributes of our class.

I've seen both used so maybe it's a matter of preference, but I wonder if there are any guidelines people have had success with. Specifically:

- Are there any situations where one is preferred over the other?
- Are there any "rules of thumb" for which variables get passed and which get stored?

Comment: Ask yourself whether the method should change the state of your object or whether it's supposed to generate a value for the user.

Answer (score 0):

`python` does have [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) decorator, which can be used for creating what might be described simply as computed attribute and could be read as common attribute, consider following simple example

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
    @property
    def area(self):
        return self.width * self.height
rect = Rectangle(5,10)
print(rect.area)
rect.width = 7
print(rect.area)
```

output

```
50
70
```

If you try to set `rect.area` for example `rect.area = 180` you will get `AttributeError: can't set attribute`.

More advanced usage of `property` allow also for providing action to do on setting and deleting attribute, see linked docs.